# How to get EntityManager from spring JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hibernate-search

We have our repository which extends the JpaRepository, and we use this to save/modify our data. On top of this we have hibernate search, so when we update entities in the repo they are also updated in our search index. As part of our hibernate search implementation we need the ability to select objects from the repo (findById), and then call `fullTextEntityManager.index(object)`.

To do this we need to have access to the associated EntityManager of that object, and I can't figure out how we are supposed to access it.

We have tried autowiring an EntityManagerFactory, but that doesn't work, I'm assuming because it isn't the same EntityManager associated with getting the object from the repository.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/accessing-the-entitymanager-from-spring-data-jpa
did you try to this article?

Comment: Did you try to use @PersistentContext to autowired a EntityManager bean?

Comment: @codeadd Just re-read the article and realized I had made a mistake within my original attempt, it now runs without error, but the result is not expected. I'll raise the issue on the hibernate forums as it seems to be a separate issue, thanks for the help!

Comment: Spoke to soon, using that method throws the same error as autowiring it did, it complains that "The instance was not associated with this session" meaning the EntityManager I am using `.index(object)` on is not the same EntityManager which retrieved the object when I called `.findById(x)` earlier. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure everything runs in the **same transaction**, else it won't work. If you didn't put an `@Transactional` on the method invoking both the `findById` and which is invoking the other methods for indexing it will use 2 different `EntityManager`s as both run in seperated transactions.

Comment: Thank you! I had several transactions but not in the right place as I had moved them all around when I couldn't get the access to the Entity Manager working properly. Wrapped the whole method in a transaction and it worked! Thank you!!!